# Factoring out common parts of Spirit rules

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a lot of rules that have common prefix and suffix:

```
rule = begin_stuff >> some >> other >> stuff >> end_stuff.
```

(where `begin_stuff` and `end_stuff` are composed from literals)

I wanted to be able to say

```
 rule = wrapped(some >> other >> stuff);
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
  template<typename Rule> Rule wrapped(Rule inside) 
  {
    Rule result;
    result = begin_stuff >> inside >> end_stuff;
    return result;
  }
```

but all I get is lots of compile-time assertions from Qi.

How can I refactor Spirit rules in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the [Qi Confix Parser Derective](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/confix.html) from [Spirit Repository](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/index.html). It is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for 'subrules' (that Spirit V1/classical used to have). These are obsolete now.

Have a look at

- c++11 `auto` and `BOOST_AUTO`

  ```
  auto subexpression = int_ >> ',' >> double_;
  qi::rule<It> rule  = "A:" >> subexpression >> "Rest:" >> (subexpression % eol);
  ```

  There used to be issues with using `auto` on Spirit rules (notably with MSVC) (see [Zero to 60 MPH in 2 seconds!](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/zero-to-60-mph-in-2-seconds/) and comments) but I have been informed this (soon) [is no longer an issue](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/What-happened-to-subrules-tc4636688.html):

  > ```
  > Yep. Anyway,FYI, it's fixed in Spirit-3. You can 
  > use auto all you want. 
  >
  > Regards, 
  > -- 
  > Joel de Guzman
  > ```
- [qi::lazy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/lazy.html)
- [inherited arguments](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal._code__phrase_role__identifier___r1__phrase___code_______code__phrase_role__identifier__r10__phrase___code_) - introduced in the [Mini XML - ASTs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html) tutorial

Here is a proof of concept that passes a common subrule to different 'compound' rules to allow for wrapping in `()`, `[]` or `{}`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

template <typename R>
    void test(const std::string& input, R const& rule)
{
    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,rule,qi::space);
    std::cout << "'" << input << "'\tparse " << (ok?"success":"failure") << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    typedef qi::rule<It,                    qi::space_type> common_rule;
    typedef qi::rule<It, void(common_rule), qi::space_type> compound_rule;

    common_rule common = qi::int_;

    compound_rule 
        in_parens   = qi::lit('(') >> qi::_r1 >> ')',
        in_brackets = qi::lit('[') >> qi::_r1 >> ']',
        in_braces   = qi::lit('{') >> qi::_r1 >> '}';

    test("{ 231 }"  , in_braces  (phx::ref(common )) );
    test("{ hello }", in_braces  (phx::val("hello")) );

    test("( 231 )"  , in_parens  (phx::ref(common )) );
    test("( hello )", in_parens  (phx::val("hello")) );

    test("[ 231 ]"  , in_brackets(phx::ref(common )) );
    test("[ hello ]", in_brackets(phx::val("hello")) );
}
```

Output:

```
'{ 231 }'   parse success
'{ hello }' parse success
'( 231 )'   parse success
'( hello )' parse success
'[ 231 ]'   parse success
'[ hello ]' parse success
```

PS. Note the above is ***not*** a typical Spirit grammar. This way doesn't play too well when the 'common' rule would expose different attributes.

Comment: sehe, thanks for could you answer. Could you finish it? The last word "Also" tells me you had more to say...

Comment: @Arkadiy I don't remember anything specific I was going to say. Except maybe the thing about 'auto' that I did add. Cheers

Comment: Question: how do we get from val("hello") to common_rule?

Comment: @Arkadiy Erm, the compiler does the conversions. In precisely the same way as `qi::rule<It> hello_rule = "hello";` - i.e. the string literal `"hello"` is implicitely treated as `qi::lit("hello")`. [The `phx::val` is just there to make this a lazy value.]

Comment: What I don't get is the fact that compound rule has `void(common_rule)` in it, and yet we're passing a string (wrapped in val). Could we pass a parser?

Comment: @Arkadiy That is the whole point. `common_rule` is just a typedef for a specif `qi::rule<>`. Yes, of course, you can pass a parser. Which is what we _do_. For this reason I demonstrated it by passing a parser byref (`phx::ref(common)`) and a parser byval (`phx::val("hello")`). As you can see I tried to be comprehensive by showing _different_ rules, but you can just as easily pass `phx::val(uint_)` or even `phx::val('{' >> qi::double_ % ';' >> '}')`

Comment: The example you provided compiles fine for me however the output I get is:
`'{ 231 }'       parse failure` `'{ hello }'     parse failure` `'( 231 )'       parse failure` `'( hello )'     parse failure`

Any idea what that might be caused by?

Comment: Funny, seems to work if I wrap the qi::_r1 in qi::lazy() - not sure why.

Comment: @naderman I won't be near a computer to test/fix this in a while. However in the mean time I have a hunch that there is UB involved, in which case using qi::lazy effectively only _masks_ the symptom for your program. The problem would be references to temps being held inside expression templates for _r1. See here for dissection of a similar situation that exhibited this particular problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550 (and how I "fixed" it in that case...)