# Boost.Spirit.Qi crashes when assigning rule to a sequence including itself

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the following MWE:

```
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>

namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;


int main() {

    std::string input("1 2");

    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void(), qi::space_type> parser;
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void(), qi::space_type> parser2;
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void(), qi::space_type> parser3;

    parser = qi::int_[
        std::cerr << phoenix::val("First int: ") << qi::_1 << std::endl
    ];

    parser2 = qi::int_[
        std::cerr << phoenix::val("Second int: ") << qi::_1 << std::endl
    ];

    try {
        // Comment out these two lines, (finished below ...)
        parser3 = parser >> parser2;
        phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser3, qi::space);

        // ... then un-comment these lines, and the program will crash (and no
        // exception is caught below).
//        parser = parser >> parser2;
//        phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser, qi::space);
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught." << std::endl;
    }

}
```

As noted in the commented lines, if I assign a third qi::rule to a sequence of another two rules, and parse using that third rule, my program works as expected.  However, if I assign the same sequence to the first rule in the sequence, then parse using that first rule, the program will crash when I run it, apparently without even throwing an exception since the `catch (...) { . . . }` block does not execute.

So my question is: is there some rule about '`qi::rule`'s I should know that forbids assigning a sequence that contains a rule to that very same rule, or is this crash due to a bug in Boost.Spirit.Qi?

### Intent

To clarify, in light of cv_and_he's comment, my goal behind this little toy example is to figure out how to do some dynamic parser generation at runtime; specifically how to generate a rule from a sequence of rules whose count is only know at runtime, such as `parser = A1 >> A2 >> ... >> AN;`, where `N` is not known at compile-time, so I can't just hard-code one rule with a fixed number of '`>>`' that way.  This would be something akin to building a list at run time by appending elements to the end, one at a time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/847455/2417774

Comment: @cv_and_he Your link to an answer about infinite recursion provides good insight, thanks.  So apparently I made an error in thinking the rule assignment was analogous to `int i = 0; i = i + 1`, since rules in the RHS sequence aren't semantically like C++ variables, but are really non-terminals in the grammar.  So it's that I've been creating a grammar with infinite recursion?  So is the crash I'm seeing the result of running out of stack space?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your goal. Do you want to parse "1 2 3 4" as (((1 2) 3) 4)? or simply update the "value" of `parser` in a way similar to your int example? If it's the latter you can use `parser = parser.copy() >> parser2;`

Comment: Yes, it is the latter;  My goal is to form a new rule at runtime, as a sequence of non-terminals I have stored in a std::vector; I'm using a std::vector in part because I don't know the number of non-terminals in the sequence at run time, but only as the result of an earlier parse.  So early parsing drives dynamic parser rule generation later.  The parser.copy() function is a *great* thing to learn about; a _copy_ of a rule has the semantics I didn't know I was looking for, so this is very helpful.

Comment: Although I have not testet it, when your rules are similar enough, why not combine `qi::repeat` with `qi::lazy`?

Comment: @Mike M, The rules in my sequence aren't identical, so I don't see how qi::repeat would help--maybe it would if the only issue were repeating the same rule by a number of times only known at runtime--maybe that's what you were saying?  Or are you suggesting there's a way to use qi::repeat to repeat a qi::lazy that return a different rule with each repeat/invocation?

Comment: No, I meant repeating similar rules and using lazy to set the repeat count during run time. They need not be identical, but must at least deliver to the same value_type. This can be achieved by using e.g. a `vector<variant<...>>` as target type. Also the Nabalieck trick might come to mind, you can add different rules to a symbol parser during run time...

Comment: using `parser.copy()` is doing the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve, but copy() would seem to be what you're after

```
    parser = parser.copy() >> parser2;
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/903527817aef7933)**

---

#### Background

The problem is Qi takes non-terminals by reference, so you get the parser semantics a PEG grammar would suggest.

Besides that, Proto expression trees (*expression templates*) do take some of their arguments by reference.

These two combined have a potential to really mess up your life, especially when construction parsers dynamically. In short, I'd argue that, outside

- using *inherited attributes*
- and *qi::symbols* (including the Nabialek trick)

constructing rules on the fly is not well supported in Spirit V2. Proto x11 / Spirit X3 may change this for the better.

See more background here:

- [C++ Boost qi recursive rule construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405500/c-boost-qi-recursive-rule-construction/17408206#17408206)
- [Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550)
- [Can Boost Spirit Rules be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610605/can-boost-spirit-rules-be-parameterized/13623587#13623587)

---

#### Sample code

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>

namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;


int main() {

    std::string input("1 2");

    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void(), qi::space_type> parser;
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void(), qi::space_type> parser2;
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void(), qi::space_type> parser3;

    parser = qi::int_[
        std::cerr << phoenix::val("First int: ") << qi::_1 << std::endl
    ];

    parser2 = qi::int_[
        std::cerr << phoenix::val("Second int: ") << qi::_1 << std::endl
    ];

    try {
        // Comment out these two lines, (finished below ...)
        parser3 = parser >> parser2;
        phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser3, qi::space);

        parser = parser.copy() >> parser2;
        phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser, qi::space);
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught." << std::endl;
    }

}
```