# Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions

Tags: boost, c++11, boost-spirit, variadic-templates, boost-fusion

I'm looking for the simplest way to implement variadic function which takes list of boost::spirit::qi rules and expands the list into expression of format: rule1 | rule2 | rule3 |.... Let's assume that the rules synthesize no attribute. Your kind help is very much appreciated.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ph    = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;
using boost::spirit::qi::ascii::space;
using boost::spirit::iso8859_1::char_;

typedef qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,ascii::space_type> mrule_t;
typedef qi::rule< std::string::const_iterator,std::string() >   wrule_t;
```

---

```
//How to deduce expandBitwise() return type ?

template<typename T>
T expandBitwise(T& t)
{
    return t.rule_;
}

template<typename T,typename ...Tail>
T expandBitwise(T& t,Tail& ...tail)
{
    return t.rule_ | expandBitwise(tail...);
}

struct TStruct
{
    mrule_t     rule_;
    template<typename T,typename R>
    TStruct( T& rVar,const std::string&name, R& rule ) :
        rule_( qi::lit( name ) >> rule[ ph::ref( rVar )=qi::_1 ] )
        {}
};

template<typename T,typename ...Tail>
void mparse(const std::string& line,T& t,Tail& ...tail)
{
    std::string::const_iterator f,l;

    f=line.begin();
    l=line.end();
```

---

```
    // I would like to expand the rules here ...
    //if(phrase_parse(f,l,expandBitwise(t,tail...),space ) && f==l)

    if( phrase_parse(f, l, t.rule_, space ) && f==l )
        std::cout<<"Parsed:"<<line<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"Syntax error:"<<line<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    wrule_t rword=+~space;

    std::string par1,par2,par3,par4;

    TStruct r1( par1,"-a", rword );
    TStruct r2( par2,"-b", rword );
    TStruct r3( par3,"-c", rword );
    TStruct r4( par4,"-d", rword );

    mparse("abc 8.81"   ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-a atoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-b btoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-c ctoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-d dtoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Thank you for a quick hint! I've just tried your code and unless I do something wrong ... I get this output: `Syntax error:abc 8.81 Parsed:-a atoken Syntax error:-b btoken Syntax error:-c ctoken Syntax error:-d dtoken`* – [G. Civardi 2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/return-type-deduction-of-boost-spirit-expression-made-of-variadic-function-expan/16179565#comment23128636_16179565)

Okay, so, I couldn't leave it alone :/

Turns out there was **Undefined Behaviour** involved, because of the way in which parser expressions were being passed to `expandBitwise` and being copied: Boost Proto expression templates weren't designed to be copied as they may contain references to temporaries, whose lifetime ends at the end of their containing full-expression.

> See for more background, the discussion at [Zero to 60 MPH in 2 seconds!](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/zero-to-60-mph-in-2-seconds/)

After a long (long) time of tweaking with `rule_.alias()` and `boost::proto::deepcopy` I have reached the following solution (which, incidentally, doesn't need a helper function at all, anymore):

```
template<typename ...Tail>
void mparse(const std::string& line,Tail& ...tail)
{
    auto parser = boost::fusion::fold(
                boost::tie(ph::bind(&TStruct::rule_, arg1)(tail)...),
                qi::eps(false),
                deepcopy_(arg2 | arg1)
            );

    auto f=begin(line), l=end(line);

    if( qi::phrase_parse(f, l, parser, ascii::space ) )
        std::cout << "Parsed:" << line << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Syntax error:" << line << std::endl;

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

The protection against UB is the `deepcopy_()` invocation, which is a trivial polymorphic callable adaptor for `boost::proto::deepcopy`:

```
struct DeepCopy
{
    template<typename E> struct result { typedef typename boost::proto::result_of::deep_copy<E>::type type; };

    template<typename E>
        typename result<E>::type
        operator()(E const& expr) const {
            return boost::proto::deep_copy(expr);
        }
};

static const ph::function<DeepCopy> deepcopy_;
```

With this code, lo and behold, the output becomes:

```
Syntax error:abc 8.81
Remaining unparsed: 'abc 8.81'
Parsed:-a atoken
Parsed:-b btoken
Parsed:-c ctoken
Parsed:-d dtoken
Bye
```

As a bonus, the code now allows you to use Spirit's builtin debug() capabilities (uncomment that line):

```
<-d>
  <try>abc 8.81</try>
  <fail/>
</-d>
<-c>
  <try>abc 8.81</try>
  <fail/>
</-c>
<-b>
  <try>abc 8.81</try>
  <fail/>
</-b>
<-a>
  <try>abc 8.81</try>
  <fail/>
</-a>
Syntax error:abc 8.81
Remaining unparsed: 'abc 8.81'
```

> Tested with
>
> - Boost 1_54_0
> - GCC 4.7.2, 4.8.x, Clang 3.2
> - Note the `#define`s which are significant.

### FULL CODE

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ph    = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
using namespace ph::arg_names;

typedef qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,ascii::space_type> mrule_t;
typedef qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,std::string() >    wrule_t;

struct TStruct
{
    mrule_t     rule_;
    template<typename T,typename R>
    TStruct( T& rVar,const std::string&name, R& rule ) :
        rule_( qi::lit(name) >> rule[ ph::ref(rVar) = qi::_1 ] )
    { 
        rule_.name(name);
        // debug(rule_);
    }
};

struct DeepCopy
{
    template<typename E> struct result { typedef typename boost::proto::result_of::deep_copy<E>::type type; };

    template<typename E>
        typename result<E>::type
        operator()(E const& expr) const {
            return boost::proto::deep_copy(expr);
        }
};

static const ph::function<DeepCopy> deepcopy_;

template<typename ...Tail>
void mparse(const std::string& line,Tail& ...tail)
{
    auto parser = boost::fusion::fold(
                boost::tie(ph::bind(&TStruct::rule_, arg1)(tail)...),
                qi::eps(false),
                deepcopy_(arg2 | arg1)
            );

    auto f=begin(line), l=end(line);

    if( qi::phrase_parse(f, l, parser, ascii::space ) )
        std::cout << "Parsed:" << line << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Syntax error:" << line << std::endl;

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}

int main()
{
    wrule_t rword=+~ascii::space;

    std::string par1,par2,par3,par4;

    TStruct r1( par1, "-a", rword );
    TStruct r2( par2, "-b", rword );
    TStruct r3( par3, "-c", rword );
    TStruct r4( par4, "-d", rword );

    mparse("abc 8.81"   ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-a atoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-b btoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-c ctoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);
    mparse("-d dtoken"  ,r1,r2,r3,r4);

    std::cout << "Bye\n";
}
```

Comment: **BRAVISSIMO MAESTRO!** Many **THANKS** for not giving up on me and sticking with my initial specification **!!!** As stated earlier I care more about principles and insights than an elegant workaround, but I appreciate alternatives as well :-) I got stuck on this problem yesterday and your "solution" allows me to enter a few new doors :-)

Comment: Did I mention I would very much _still_ recommend using qi::symbols for this? It's less complex, and probably more compiletime/runtime efficient (well, needs profiling, but who profiles his CLI argument parser? Simpler trumps efficient here). I'm tempted to toy with a proper Proto eDSL for this task later.

Comment: Excercise on qi::symbols ( as you described in the first answer ) is on my todo list. The implementation and instruments used in this answer will keep me busy for a while :-)

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally returned the TStruct type from the `expandBitwise` helper. Fix it like so:

```
template<typename T>
auto expandBitwise(T const& t) -> decltype(t.rule_)
{
    return t.rule_;
}

template<typename T,typename ...Tail>
auto expandBitwise(T const& t,Tail const&... tail) -> decltype(t.rule_)
{
    return t.rule_ | expandBitwise(tail...);
}
```

If you want to expose attributes, the return type deduction rules become more involved. Basically, what you're doing is replicating the EDSL part of Spirit.

---

Let's swap stories...

> ### **`Clippy:`** *It looks like you are trying to write a commandline argument parser. Would you like help with that?*

Implementing the DSL mechanics for your option parser could be done more systematically by creating a new Proto Domain and actually creating the terminals. This would somehow appeal to me now.

***Alternatively*** you could take this from another angle completely, using the **[Nabialek Trick](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/nabialek-trick/)**. This happens to be an approach I played with just a few weeks ago, and I'll share with you the design I had come up with: https://gist.github.com/sehe/2a556a8231606406fe36#file-test-cpp

The important part is, where the grammar is "fixed":

```
start    = -argument % '\0';
unparsed = as_string  [ +~nul ] [ std::cerr << phx::val("ignoring unparsed argument: '") << _1 << "'\n" ];
argument = ('-' >> +shortopt) | ("--" >> longopt) >> -unparsed | unparsed;
```

The trick being in:

```
shortopt = shortNames [_a = _1] >> lazy(_a);
longopt  = longNames  [_a = _1] >> lazy(_a);
```

Where `shortNames` and `longNames` are `qi::symbols` tables of parsers, built dynamically, based on a variadic list of `CliOptions` and `CliFlags` (I pass them as a tuple, because I wanted to store the result inside the `CliOption` struct as well).

The `qi::lazy(_a)` invokes the parser that was stored in the *symbol table*.

As a bonus, my CliOptions parser has a feature to generate "Usage" information as well. The builders for parse expressions as well as usage informations are extensible.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using CliParsing::make_option;

    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    auto config = std::make_tuple(
        make_option('a', "absolutely", "absolutely"),
        make_option('b', "borked"    , "borked")    ,
        make_option('c', "completion", "completion"),
        make_option('d', "debug",      "turn on debugging"),
        make_option('e', "",           "no long name")  ,
        //make_option('f', "flungeons" , "flungeons") ,
        //make_option('g', "goofing"   , "")   ,
        //make_option('m', "monitor",    "monitoring level"),
        make_option('t', "testing"   , "testing flags"),
        make_option('\0',"file"      , "with a filename (no short name)"),

        make_option('y', "assume-yes", "always assume yes"),
        make_option('v', "verbose",    "increase verbosity level"),
        make_option('i', "increment",  "stepsize to increment with", 5)
        );

    CliParsing::OptionGrammar<It> parser(config);

    using namespace phx::arg_names;
    const auto cmdline = std::accumulate(argv+1, argv+argc, std::string(), arg1 + arg2 + '\0');

    bool ok = qi::parse(begin(cmdline), end(cmdline), parser);

    std::cout << "Parse success " << std::boolalpha << ok << "\n";
    std::cout << parser.getUsage();

    return ok? 0 : 255;
}
```

When invoked with some random arguments `-i 3 --completion -t --file=SOME.TXT -b huh?`, prints:

```
short form option --increment parsed
ignoring unparsed argument: '3'
long form switch --completion parsed
short form switch --testing parsed
long form switch --file parsed
ignoring unparsed argument: '=SOME.TXT'
short form switch --borked parsed
ignoring unparsed argument: 'huh?'

Parse success true
 --absolutely (-a)
    absolutely (flag)
 --borked (-b)
    borked (flag)
 --completion (-c)
    completion (flag)
 --debug (-d)
    turn on debugging (flag)
 -e
    no long name (flag)
 --testing (-t)
    testing flags (flag)
 --file
    with a filename (no short name) (flag)
 --assume-yes (-y)
    always assume yes (flag)
 --verbose (-v)
    increase verbosity level (flag)
 --increment (-i)
    stepsize to increment with (option with value; default '5')
```

As you can see, not all options have been implemented yet (notably, `--` to mark the end of the option list).

Comment: Thank you for a quick hint! I've just tried your code and unless I do something wrong ... I get this output:
Syntax error:abc 8.81
Parsed:-a atoken
Syntax error:-b btoken
Syntax error:-c ctoken
Syntax error:-d dtoken

Comment: Well, I didn't hope you needed help debugging your grammar. I assumed the question was about getting your `expandBitwise` function template to compile. Did you have some time to look at the Nabialek Trick (using `qi::symbols` instead of a 'variadic' expression of the `r1|r2|r3|r4` form)?

Comment: As guessed right :-), I've been working on a command-line parser. Mainly as a exercise to try wide variety of approaches related to boost spirit and c++ in general. Thank you very much for sharing your code snippets with me !

Comment: Well, prepare to upvote! I just spent ~3 hours debugging your grammar. It turned out to be trickier than one would like. I [posted another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16181550/85371) detailing the solution I came up with and full explanations. Cheers.

Comment: You just made my **SPIRIT** day today! **Thanks again** :-)