# Boost.Spirit.Qi: dynamically create "difference" parser at parse time

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

A "difference" parser can be created by the binary `-`(minus) operator:

```
rule = qi::char_ - qi::lit("}}")
```

or even compound differences:

```
rule = qi::char_ - qi::lit("}}") - qi::lit("]]")
```

But how could I generate the whole result of the difference parser at the parse time?
I'm guessing it might be some kind of form like below:

```
phoenix::function<difference_parser_impl> difference_parser;
rule = qi::lazy(difference_parser(qi::char_, {"}}", "]]"}));
```

Here, the `{..., ..., ...}` part would actually be a stl container, but it is not the point; I can handle that part.

I have found the template `qi::difference<Left, Right>` -- but I  couldn't find out how to use it.

Comment: In meta-programming, I'd prefer to write `decltype(qi::char_ - (expr1 | expr2 | expr3))` anyways. No need to know the actual types. However, I came up with an elegant solution, I think, for which this isn't relevant. :)

Comment: You're right, that's the smart way to do it in meta-programming. I even tried `decltype(qi::char_ - std::declval<qi::lit>() - std::declval<qi::lit>())` in this situation... but it fails on creating dynamic parsers, because the first subtraction and latter respectively have different types generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you're not looking for a dynamic "difference" expression so much, but rather a dynamic "variadic alternative (a|b|c...)" expression:

*`expr - a - b - c` is equivalent to `expr - (a|b|c)`*

You could then easily achieve the difference using either:

```
expr - orCombine(alternatives)
```

or

```
!orCombine(alternatives) >> expr
```

Now, getting this done has many rough edges, which I'll explain first. Luckily, there is a simpler way, using `qi::symbols`, which I'll demonstrate right after that.

### The tricky stuff

If you want, you can "generate" alternative parser expressions on-demand, with a fair bit of wizardry. I showed how to do this in this answer:

- [Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550)

But

1. it is fraught with pitfalls (as proto expressions don't lend themselves to copying well)<sup>1</sup>
2. it conveniently used variadics in order to avoid intermediate storage (note the `deepcopy_` to ward of Undefined Behaviour):

   ```
   template<typename ...Expr>
   void parse_one_of(Expr& ...expressions)
   {
       auto parser = boost::fusion::fold(
                   boost::tie(expressions...),
                   qi::eps(false),
                   deepcopy_(arg2 | arg1)
               );
   ```

   Seeing how you have a need for *truly* dynamic composition of the alternative parser, I don't see how this could be adapted to your needs without an explosion  of complexity and opportunity for subtle error (***believe me, I already tried***).

So, instead I recommend a tried & true approach that "abuses" an existing "dynamic" parser:

### Simplify using `qi::symbols`

This idea borrows losely from the well-famed "Nabialek Trick". It uses qi::symbols, and consequently has excellent runtime performance characteristics<sup>2</sup>.

With no further ado, this is an example of how you could use it, starting from a vector of string literals:

```
template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, std::string(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        static const std::vector<std::string> not_accepted { "}}", "]]" };

        using namespace qi;
        exclude = exclusions(not_accepted);
        start = *(char_ - exclude);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> start;

    typedef qi::symbols<char, qi::unused_type> Exclude;
    Exclude exclude;

    template<typename Elements>
    Exclude exclusions(Elements const& elements) {
        Exclude result;

        for(auto& el : elements)
            result.add(el);

        return result;
    }
};
```

A full working sample of this is [here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ddbb2549674bfed90e3c8df33b048574-7616891f9fd25da6391c2728423de797](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ddbb2549674bfed90e3c8df33b048574-7616891f9fd25da6391c2728423de797) and it prints

```
parse success
data: 123
trailing unparsed: ']] 4'
```

### Full code

For future reference:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, std::string(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        static const std::vector<std::string> not_accepted { "}}", "]]" };

        using namespace qi;
        exclude = exclusions(not_accepted);
        start = *(char_ - exclude);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> start;

    typedef qi::symbols<char, qi::unused_type> Exclude;
    Exclude exclude;

    template<typename Elements>
    Exclude exclusions(Elements const& elements) {
        Exclude result;

        for(auto& el : elements)
            result.add(el);

        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "1 2 3]] 4";
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    It f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    parser<It> p;
    std::string data;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data);
    if (ok)   
    {
        std::cout << "parse success\n";
        std::cout << "data: " << data << "\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I believe this problem is about to be removed in the upcoming new version of Spirit (currently dubbed "Spirit X3" for the experimental version)

<sup>2</sup> It uses [Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to lookup the matches

Comment: The "wizardly" way looks semantically correct, but I can feel that it has a lot of *bad* stuff. `qi::symbols` looks much smarter. But I didn't know that `qi::symbols` of having `bool` as the result type having an effect similar to, say... `eps(bool)`. I'm guessing it becomes a bool parser when used alone, but becomes a negated parser when subtracted from a char_ set.

Comment: @saki7 The 'value type' of the symbols lookup is irrelevant: only the fact that an entry is found in the trie matters (I changed the code to use `qi::unused_type` instead of bool).