# Statefulness of Spirit V2 and X3

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

What is the intent of Spirit X3 being so much 'stateless'?

### Bad aspects of 'states' in Spirit V2

Looking back to Spirit V2, the "grammar" was, say, conceptually stateful - in many ways. This is because the grammar was a class instance.

Basically, there are lots of bad aspects for making your grammar -- or even any single rule -- to be stateful:

- It might make your grammar non-re-entrant;
- It might add thread-unsafety to your grammar instance;
- Self-managed 'flag' is a disaster.

Theoretically speaking, adding an external state makes your grammar non-trivial.

### Really need no state?

In contrast, you can say any parser is stateful (because it parses the current context and context is the state). Below is a good case of additional 'context' added by a programmer:

```
quoted_string_ = as_string [omit [char_("'\"") [_a = _1]] >> *(char_ - lit(_a)) >> lit(_a)]
```

`qi::locals` was a good sign of **non**-external states.

There were also 'external states' which a programmer could add to his grammar, and they were just doing something wrong in most cases:

```
func_call_ = func_name_ >> lit('(') >> eps [ref(is_inside_function_call) = true] >> ...
```

But still, there were some corner cases where external states being useful.

```
macro_type_1_ =
    lit("{{{") [PUSH_STATE(macro_ctx, Macro::Type1)] >> (
        ((any_expr_ - end_of_macro_ctx_) >> lit("}}}") >> eps [POP_STATE(macro_ctx)]) |
        (eps [POP_STATE(macro_ctx)] >> eps [_pass = false])
    )
;
macro_type_2_ =
    lit("[[[") [PUSH_STATE(macro_ctx, Macro::Type2)] >> (
        ((any_expr_ - end_of_macro_ctx_) >> lit("]]]") >> eps [POP_STATE(macro_ctx)]) |
        (eps [POP_STATE(macro_ctx)] >> eps [_pass = false])
    )
;
```

Above is an example of some arbitrary context-sensitive language. Here I am adding a 'context stack' by emulating a 'destructor' for the sub rule. This might be a good case of using a special variant of Nabialec Trick where `end_of_macro_ctx_` being `qi::symbols` instance.

(See [Boost.Spirit.Qi: dynamically create "difference" parser at parse time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000897/boost-spirit-qi-dynamically-create-difference-parser-at-parse-time) for possible implementation detail)

You can't use `qi::locals` here, because there are no guarantee for the lifetime of `qi::locals`. So you should use a global variable (i.e. member variable for your grammar class instance).

Inherited attributes? Maybe. If you are willing to pass the same variable to every single rule.

### External states for grammar itself

Speaking about external states, there are even more fundamental stuff which a programmer might want to add to his grammar.

```
on_error<fail>(root_, phx::bind(&my_logger, &MyLogger::error, _1, _2, _3, _4));
```

You can't do this anymore on X3.

### Statelessness of X3

X3 is expecting an user to define his every single rule in namespace scope, with auto-consted instance.

Okay, now let's take a look at the implementation of `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE`. It is basically doing only one thing:

> #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(your_rule, <unspecified>) template <unspecified> <unspecified> parse_rule(decltype(your_rule), <unspecified>...) { <unspecified> }

The first argument of `parse_rule()` is decltype-d to given rule's unique type.

This means two things:

1. X3 is fully relying on ADL call to `parse_rule()`.
2. `parse_rule()` must be defined in namespace scope.

You can't specialize a template function for an instance.  There's no way of telling X3 to use any of my instance variables.

I lied. You can do this if you want:

```
static inline MyLogger& use_my_logger_please() {
    static MyLogger instance; return instance;
}
```

or

```
#define MY_BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(my_rule, <unspecified>, my_logger_f) <unspecified>
MY_BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(rule_1_, ..., std::bind([] (MyLogger& l, std::string const& msg) { l << msg; }, this->logger_instance_, std::placeholders::_1))
```

Really?

Comment: Am I correct in boiling your question down to: "What is the intent of xxx being so much 'stateless'?".
The intent is almost always, separation of concerns -> loose coupling -> more reusability.

Comment: Statelessness is a good thing. My point is: there should be no difference between (a) arbitrary member variable instance and (b) inherited context variable passed to every single sub rule.

Comment: This seems like a ranty blog post, not a question. "Self-managed 'flag' is a disaster." - what does it even mean? "You can't do this anymore on X3." - you completely fail to specify _what_ you think cannot be done in X3. Ironically, you can (of course) do error handling in X3. It's just poorly documented.

Comment: This is a question. I have asked a *question* on the first sentence. Of course I know there's on_error for X3 too. But how can you pass your own variable to your on_error()? How can you specify your custom std::ofstream to be used by on_error at runtime? on_error is a template function with a fixed signature. You can't specialize a template function for a instance. Did you read that part on my question?

Comment: Error handling is just one example. The main subject of this question is about X3's constness. If a rule must be declared auto-const in a namespace scope, and X3 is expecting ADL for an unique type, is there any way to modify the target of ref(any_variable) specified by your rule? Without using static variables, at runtime?

Comment: @saki7 I tried to give you my brain dump [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469919/85371). If you really want to know "why", you should probably ask the devs on the [spirit-general] mailing list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You make a number of unsubstantiated claims in your "question" article.

I recognize much of the sentiment that shines through your rant, but I find it hard to constructively respond when there is so much debatable in it.

### New Possibilities

> X3 is expecting an user to define his every single rule in namespace scope, with auto-consted instance.

This is simply not true. X3 doesn't do that. It could be said that X3 *promotes* that pattern to enable key features like

- recursive grammars
- separation of parsers across translation units

On the flip side, there's not always a need for any of that.

The very value-orientedness of X3 enables new patterns to achieve things. I'm quite fond of being able to do things like:

#### Stateful Parser Factories

```
auto make_parser(char delim) {
     return lexeme [ delim >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_(delim)) >> delim ];
}
```

Indeed, you might "need" x3::rule to achieve attribute coercion (like qi::transfom_attr):

```
auto make_parser(char delim) {
     return rule<struct _, std::string> {} = lexeme [ delim >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_(delim)) >> delim ];
}
```

In fact, I've used this pattern to make quick-and-dirty `as<T>[]` directive: [Understanding the List Operator (%) in Boost.Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816662/understanding-the-list-operator-in-boost-spirit/33817135#33817135).

```
auto make_parser(char delim) {
     return as<std::string> [ lexeme [ delim >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_(delim)) >> delim ] ];
}
```

Nothing prevents you from using a dynamic parser factory like that to use context from surrounding state.

#### Stateful Semantic Actions

Semantic actions are copied by value, but they can freely refer to external state. When using factory functions, they can, again, use surrounding state.

#### Stateful directives

The only way directives to create state on the fly is to extend the actual context object. The `x3::with<>` directive supports this, e.g. [Boost Spirit X3 cannot compile repeat directive with variable factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624149/boost-spirit-x3-cannot-compile-repeat-directive-with-variable-factor)

This can be used to pigeon-hole unlimited amounts of state, e.g. by just side-channel passing a (smart) pointer/reference to your parser state.

#### Custom Parsers

Custom parsers are a surprisingly simple way to get a lot of power in X3. See for an example:

[Spirit-Qi: How can I write a nonterminal parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669936/spirit-qi-how-can-i-write-a-nonterminal-parser)

I personally think custom parsers are more elegant than anything like the BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE/_DEFINE/_INSTANTIATE dance. I admit I've never created anything requiring multi-TU parsers in pure X3 yet (I tend to use X3 for small, independent parsers), but I intuitively prefer building my own TU-separation logic building from `x3::parser_base` over the "blessed" macros mentioned above. See also this discussion: [Design/structure X3 parser more like Qi parser](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Design-structure-X3-parser-more-like-Qi-parser-td4690205.html)

#### Error/success handling

The compiler tutorials show how to trigger handlers for specific rules using a marker base-class for the rule tag type. I've one day figured out the mechanics, but sadly I don't remember all the details and [LiveCoding.tv](https://www.liveedu.tv/sehe/ZWroO-answering-boost-questions-daily/) seems to have lost my live-stream on the topic.

I encourage you to look at the compiler samples (they're in the source tree only).

## Summarizing

I can see how you notice negative differences. It's important to realize that X3 is less mature, aims to be more light-weight, so some things are simply not implemented. Also note that X3 enables *many* things in more elegant ways than previously possible. The fact that most things interact more naturally with c++14  core language features is a big boon.

If you want read more about what things disappoint me about X3, see the introductory discussion in [that linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624149/boost-spirit-x3-cannot-compile-repeat-directive-with-variable-factor), some discussions in chat (like [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/discussing-x3-advantages-vs-qi)).

I hope my counter rant helps you in journey learning X3. I tried to substantiate as many things as I could, though I freely admit I sometimes still prefer Qi.

Comment: Is `return rule<struct _, std::string> = ` missing an initializer or am I missing something?

Comment: @ildjarn Indeed. Fixed. (This is my daily reminder why I should never include untested code, not even 3 lines... :))

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. Good catch on actual impl and real-life analysis!