# Boost Spirit Qi crashes for memory violation

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

But I cannot figure out why...?

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2912593bb421a35e

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace bsq = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{        
    std::uint16_t major, minor, build, revision;

    auto versionParser =
        bsq::uint_
        >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_)
        >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_)
        >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_);

    std::string version = "3.5.1";

    auto start = version.begin();
    if (!bsq::parse(start, version.end(), versionParser, major, minor, build, revision))
    {
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
    }

    std::cout << major << "-" << minor << "-" << build << "-" << revision << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The call to `parse()` causes a memory  access violation.

I swear I had this working at one time but... maybe I was daydreaming. I've tried on Windows with Visual Studio 2017 and also on Coliru with clang. I cannot see the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `auto` expressions to capture rules, which deduces the types from the parser expressions. That type is a proto-expression tree, which captures any relations by reference, but that means many of _the intermediates are gone after the end of the enclosing [*full-expresion*](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#def:full-expression) (see [C++: Life span of temporary arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506793/c-life-span-of-temporary-arguments)).

This is pretty well-known, as you can see here:

- [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)
- [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909)
- [undefined behaviour somewhere in boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410498/undefined-behaviour-somewhere-in-boostspiritqiphrase-parse)
- And some more

Here's the simplest fix:

```
auto versionParser = bsq::copy(
    bsq::uint_
    >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_)
    >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_)
    >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_));
```

If you *also fix* the missing intialization of the local variables it works correctly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd704b7026c7fb3e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace bsq = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{    
    std::cout << "BOOST_VERSION: " << BOOST_VERSION << std::endl;

    std::uint16_t major = 0, minor = 0, build = 0, revision = 0;

    auto versionParser = bsq::copy(
        bsq::uint_
        >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_)
        >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_)
        >> -('.' >> bsq::uint_));

    std::string version = "3.5.1";

    auto start = version.begin();
    if (!bsq::parse(start, version.end(), versionParser, major, minor, build, revision))
    {
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
    }

    std::cout << major << "-" << minor << "-" << build << "-" << revision << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
BOOST_VERSION: 106600
3-5-1-0
```

### Additional Notes

1. To avoid the whole "unitialized attribute" situation, let's make it so the parser assigns to all elements, even if unspecified in the input text:

   ```
       >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
       >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
       >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
   ```
2. To diagnose errors where there is trailing "garbage" (like with `"3.4bogus"`), you could add a check that the full input is parsed:

   ```
   auto versionParser = bsq::copy(
       bsq::uint_
       >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
       >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
       >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
       >> bsq::eoi);
   ```
3. Because a version is semantically a tuple, why not represent it as such?

   ```
   using Version = std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t>;
   Version parsed;

   if (!bsq::parse(version.begin(), version.end(), versionParser, parsed))
       std::cout << "Error!\n";
   ```

   That way you can even say:

   ```
   using boost::fusion::operator<<;

   auto obsolete = parsed < Version(3, 4, 0, 0);
   std::cout << "Version " << parsed << " " << (obsolete? "too old" : "supported") << "\n";
   ```

Combining those:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64b16260c559556e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace bsq = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {    
    auto versionParser = bsq::copy(
        bsq::uint_
        >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
        >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
        >> ('.' >> bsq::uint_ | bsq::attr(0))
        >> bsq::eoi);

    std::string version = "3.5.1";

    using Version = std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t>;
    Version parsed;

    if (!bsq::parse(version.begin(), version.end(), versionParser, parsed))
        std::cout << "Error!\n";

    using boost::fusion::operator<<;

    auto obsolete = parsed < Version(3, 4, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Version " << parsed << " " << (obsolete? "too old" : "supported") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Version (3 5 1 0) supported
```

### `std::tuple` sucks?

I agree. So, equivalently write your own struct:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86b37d7460bd6db1)</kbd>**

```
struct Version {
    uint16_t major, minor, revision, build;

    auto key() const { return std::tie(major, minor, revision, build); }
    bool operator<(Version const& b) const { return key() < b.key(); }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Version, major, minor, revision, build)
```

### Gettin' With The Times

Note that Spirit X3 ([Getting into boost spirit; Qi or X3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990661/getting-into-boost-spirit-qi-or-x3/52991170#52991170)) doesn't have the `auto`-issues that you ran into:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93a33781789224ea)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bsx = boost::spirit::x3;

struct Version {
    uint16_t major, minor, revision, build;

    auto key() const { return std::tie(major, minor, revision, build); }
    bool operator<(Version const& b) const { return key() < b.key(); }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Version, major, minor, revision, build)

int main() {    
    auto versionParser = bsx::uint_
        >> ('.' >> bsx::uint_ | bsx::attr(0))
        >> ('.' >> bsx::uint_ | bsx::attr(0))
        >> ('.' >> bsx::uint_ | bsx::attr(0))
        >> bsx::eoi;

    std::string version = "3.5.1";

    Version parsed;

    if (!parse(version.begin(), version.end(), versionParser, parsed))
        std::cout << "Error!\n";

    using boost::fusion::operator<<;

    auto obsolete = parsed < Version{3, 4, 0, 0};
    std::cout << "Version " << parsed << " " << (obsolete? "too old" : "supported") << "\n";
}
```

Also printing the same.

Comment: Added three notes for improvement and two more chapters with live samples.

Comment: Thank you, @sehe, I can always count on you when I have Spirit questions. :)