# Boost spirit x3 - lazy parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

Does latest `boost::spirit::x3` implement `lazy` parser? I have found it in [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/auxiliary.html)  but cannot find it in [source code on github](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/tree/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/auxiliary) and can't use `boost::spirit::x3::lazy`. Am I missing something or lazy parsers were removed from `spirit` or renamed or somthng else?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/530

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I would try my hand here.

What is needed is some type-erasure around the iterator and attribute types. This is getting very close to the interface of a `qi::rule` in the old days.

> To be complete we could actually also erase or transform contexts (e.g. to propagate the skipper inside the lazy rule), but I chose for simplicity here.
>
> In many cases the parsers to be lazily invoked might be lexemes anyways (as in the sample I will use)

In our use-case, let's parse these inputs:

```
integer_value: 42
quoted_string: "hello world"
bool_value: true
double_value: 3.1415926
```

We'll use a variant attribute type, and start with creating a `lazy_rule` parser that will allow us to erase the types:

```
using Value = boost::variant<int, bool, double, std::string>;
using It    = std::string::const_iterator;
using Rule  = x3::any_parser<It, Value>;
```

### Passing The Lazy Subject Around

Now, where do we "get" the lazy subject from?

In Spirit Qi, we had the [Nabialek Trick](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+nabialek). This would use `qi::locals<>` or [inherited attributes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/attributes/nonterminal_attributes.html), which basically both boiled down to using Phoenix lazy actors (`qi::_r1` or `qi::_a` etc) to evaluate to a value *from parser context* at runtime.

In X3 there is no Phoenix, and we will have to manipulate the context using semantic actions ourselves.

The basic building block for this is the [`x3::with<T>[]` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+x3+with+context)¹. Here's what we'll end up using as the parser:

```
x3::symbols<Rule> options;
```

Now we can add any parse expression to the options, by saying e.g. `options.add("anything", x3::eps);`.

```
auto const parser = x3::with<Rule>(Rule{}) [
    set_context<Rule>[options] >> ':' >> lazy<Rule>
];
```

This adds a `Rule` value to the context, which can be set (`set_context`) and "executed" (`lazy`).

Like I said, we have to manipulate the context manually, so let's define some helpers that do this:

```
template <typename Tag>
struct set_context_type {
    template <typename P>
    auto operator[](P p) const {
        auto action = [](auto& ctx) {
            x3::get<Tag>(ctx) = x3::_attr(ctx);
        };
        return x3::omit [ p [ action ] ];
    }
};

template <typename Tag>
struct lazy_type : x3::parser<lazy_type<Tag>> {
    using attribute_type = typename Tag::attribute_type; // TODO FIXME?

    template<typename It, typename Ctx, typename RCtx, typename Attr>
    bool parse(It& first, It last, Ctx& ctx, RCtx& rctx, Attr& attr) const {
        auto& subject = x3::get<Tag>(ctx);

        It saved = first;
        x3::skip_over(first, last, ctx);
        if (x3::as_parser(subject).parse(first, last,
                                         std::forward<Ctx>(ctx),
                                         std::forward<RCtx>(rctx), attr)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            first = saved;
            return false;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T> static const set_context_type<T> set_context{};
template <typename T> static const lazy_type<T> lazy{};
```

That's really all there is to it.

### Demo Time

In this demo, we run the above inputs (in function `run_tests()`) and it will use the parser as shown:

```
auto run_tests = [=] {
    for (std::string const& input : {
            "integer_value: 42",
            "quoted_string: \"hello world\"",
            "bool_value: true",
            "double_value: 3.1415926",
        })
    {
        Value attr;
        std::cout << std::setw(36) << std::quoted(input);
        if (phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), parser, x3::space, attr)) {
            std::cout << " -> success (" << attr << ")\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << " -> failed\n";
        }
    }
};
```

First we will run:

```
options.add("integer_value", x3::int_);
options.add("quoted_string", as<std::string> [
        // lexeme is actually redundant because we don't use surrounding skipper yet
        x3::lexeme [ '"' >> *('\\' >> x3::char_ | ~x3::char_('"')) >> '"' ]
    ]);
run_tests();
```

Which will print:

```
"integer_value: 42"                  -> success (42)
"quoted_string: \"hello world\""     -> success (hello world)
"bool_value: true"                   -> failed
"double_value: 3.1415926"            -> failed
```

Now, we can demonstrate the dynamic nature of that parser, by extending `options`:

```
options.add("double_value", x3::double_);
options.add("bool_value", x3::bool_);

run_tests();
```

And the output becomes:

```
"integer_value: 42"                  -> success (42)
"quoted_string: \"hello world\""     -> success (hello world)
"bool_value: true"                   -> success (true)
"double_value: 3.1415926"            -> success (3.14159)
```

> Note, I threw in another helper `as<>` that makes it easier to coerce the attribute type to `std::string` there. It's an evolution of [ideas in earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457868/statefulness-of-spirit-v2-and-x3/45469919#45469919)

### Full Listing Live On Coliru

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fd7c70fef082e6b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace {
    template <typename T>
    struct as_type {
        template <typename...> struct Tag{};

        template <typename P>
        auto operator[](P p) const {
            return x3::rule<Tag<T, P>, T> {"as"} = x3::as_parser(p);
        }
    };

    template <typename Tag>
    struct set_lazy_type {
        template <typename P>
        auto operator[](P p) const {
            auto action = [](auto& ctx) {
                x3::get<Tag>(ctx) = x3::_attr(ctx);
            };
            return x3::omit [ p [ action ] ];
        }
    };

    template <typename Tag>
    struct do_lazy_type : x3::parser<do_lazy_type<Tag>> {
        using attribute_type = typename Tag::attribute_type; // TODO FIXME?

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename RCtx, typename Attr>
        bool parse(It& first, It last, Ctx& ctx, RCtx& rctx, Attr& attr) const {
            auto& subject = x3::get<Tag>(ctx);

            It saved = first;
            x3::skip_over(first, last, ctx);
            if (x3::as_parser(subject).parse(first, last,
                                             std::forward<Ctx>(ctx),
                                             std::forward<RCtx>(rctx), attr)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                first = saved;
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    template <typename T> static const as_type<T>       as{};
    template <typename T> static const set_lazy_type<T> set_lazy{};
    template <typename T> static const do_lazy_type<T>  do_lazy{};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::left;

    using Value = boost::variant<int, bool, double, std::string>;
    using It    = std::string::const_iterator;
    using Rule  = x3::any_parser<It, Value>;

    x3::symbols<Rule> options;

    auto const parser = x3::with<Rule>(Rule{}) [
        set_lazy<Rule>[options] >> ':' >> do_lazy<Rule>
    ];

    auto run_tests = [=] {
        for (std::string const input : {
                "integer_value: 42",
                "quoted_string: \"hello world\"",
                "bool_value: true",
                "double_value: 3.1415926",
            })
        {
            Value attr;
            std::cout << std::setw(36) << std::quoted(input);
            if (phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), parser, x3::space, attr)) {
                std::cout << " -> success (" << attr << ")\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << " -> failed\n";
            }
        }
    };

    std::cout << "Supporting only integer_value and quoted_string:\n";
    options.add("integer_value", x3::int_);
    options.add("quoted_string", as<std::string> [
            // lexeme is actually redundant because we don't use surrounding skipper yet
            x3::lexeme [ '"' >> *('\\' >> x3::char_ | ~x3::char_('"')) >> '"' ]
        ]);
    run_tests();

    std::cout << "\nAdded support for double_value and bool_value:\n";
    options.add("double_value", x3::double_);
    options.add("bool_value", x3::bool_);

    run_tests();
}
```

Printing the full output of:

```
Supporting only integer_value and quoted_string:
"integer_value: 42"                  -> success (42)
"quoted_string: \"hello world\""     -> success (hello world)
"bool_value: true"                   -> failed
"double_value: 3.1415926"            -> failed

Added support for double_value and bool_value:
"integer_value: 42"                  -> success (42)
"quoted_string: \"hello world\""     -> success (hello world)
"bool_value: true"                   -> success (true)
"double_value: 3.1415926"            -> success (3.14159)
```

---

¹ sadly the documentation is missing in action

Comment: you are now officially my personal spirit hero :D

Comment: :bows: Cheers. I posted the proof-of-concept idea on that Github issue so maybe it sparks some more general feature ideas

Comment: Hah. Using `x3::any_parser` shaves off 25 lines of code (and adds the context support and [test-cases](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/master/test/x3/any_parser.cpp)). Compare [before](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daa5fd0cf1ba85c9) vs [after](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36717769d5a83d36). /HT @Kojoley over [on github](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/530). Answer updated.

Comment: As usually, a solid answer from  sehe. Unfortunatley these days (june 2022) the examples at coliru fails the tests - all failed :(

Comment: @Olx :derp: you can use the [before](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daa5fd0cf1ba85c9) link from my previous comment. Somehow I never noticed that the suggestion to switch to `x3::any_parser` broke all the test cases - I must have been focusing on the fact that it compiled and ran. Will see whether I can salvage the simplification

Comment: @Olx fixed the answer version; the `any_rule` doesn't honour the skipper from context, so I added that logic to `do_lazy_type`. Also updated github https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/530#issuecomment-1166367022