# Misuse of boost::phoenix::static_cast_ to get object behind placeholder

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

Here is my issue. I experiment using boost::spirit::qi and am trying using placeholders like "_1" and "_a". I would like to access the underlying object "behind" a boost::qi/phoenix placeholder but I'm a bit struggling here.

Let's say I have the following class:

```cpp
class Tag {
public:
  Tag() = default; // Needed by qi
  Tag(std::uint8_t _raw_tag) : m_raw_tag( _raw_tag ) {}

  std::uint8_t get_size() { return m_raw_tag & 0b111; }
  std::uint8_t get_type() { return m_raw_tag & 0b1000; }

private:
  std::uint8_t m_raw_tag;
};
```

I have to parse frames starting with a tag byte that gives information about what I have to read next. To do this, I have written little helper class named Tag that unmasks these pieces of information like the type of the tag or size of the piece of data to come next. I always store the data in an `std::uint32_t` but it is possible that the size of the data is 3 bytes and not something pre-defined like 1, 2 or 4 in which case I can respectively use `qi::byte` or `qi::big_word` or `qi::big_qword` (assuming the big endianness). Therefore, I'm thinking about reading the data byte after byte and bit-shifting them in the output `std::uint32_t`.
That would give such a parser in pseudo cpp code:

```cpp
template<typename _Iterator>
struct Read_frame : qi::grammar<_Iterator, std::uint32_t(), qi::locals<std::uint8_t>> {
  Read_frame() : Read_frame::base_type(data_parser)
  {
    using boost::spirit::qi::byte_;
    using boost::spirit::qi::omit;
    using boost::spirit::qi::repeat;
    using boost::spirit::qi::_val;
    using namespace qi::labels;
    tag_parser %= byte_;
    // we read what's in the tag but we don't store it
    // Call the method get_size() of Tag is my issue, I don't know how to do it
    data_parser %= omit[tag_parser[ _a = _1.get_size()]] >> eps[_val = 0] 
      >> repeat(_a)[ byte_[ _val += (_1 << (--_a * 8)) ];
  }

  qi::rule<_Iterator, std::uint32_t(), qi::locals<std::uint8_t>> data_parser;
  qi::rule<_Iterator, Tag()> tag_parser;
};
```

The line:

```cpp
data_parser %= omit[context_tag[ _a = _1.get_size()]] >> eps[_val = 0]
```

is where my problem lies. I don't know how to access method of Tag in a semantic actions. Thereby I thought about using `boost::phoenix::static_cast_<Tag*>(&_1)->get_size()` or something alike but it does not work.
This is the first time I'm using the whole `boost::spirit` thing along with `boost::phoenix` and to be quite honest I don't think I really understood how the placeholders in `boost` work nor the principle of `boost::phoenix::static_cast_`. That's why I'm here gently asking for your help :). If you need more details, I will give them to you with pleasure

Thanks in advance,

A newbie with boost spirit

Comment: Before I answer this, what is the goal? The code you show would lead to `{0b0001, 1} → 1` and `{0b0010, 1, 0} → 2`. For most applications (like variable length integer encoding) I'd expect the shift to be by 8 bits, not 1? Fot now I'll go from what your code currently does.

Comment: @sehe You are right that's a mistake on me. I edited it thx :)

Comment: Uhoh. I won't change my answer to reflect that - too many live examples. Note though that the version without mutating state is much less tricky here due to implicit int promotion rules: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/xMGdx6x3h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic actions are lazy phoenix actors. That is, they are "deferred functions". You can also see them as dynamically defined composed functions.

The "value behind a placeholder" depends on the context. That context is runtime. The Phoenix transformation ("evaluation") uses that context to retrieve the actual object behind the placeholder *during invocation*.

The last part is the point: any runtime effect must be deferred to *during invocation*. That means that you need a Phoenix actor to access the `get_size()` method and lazily invoke it.

Clumsy? You bet. The whole semantic-action eDSL is limited. Luckily, there are many ways to approach this:

- you can use `phoenix::bind` with a pointer-to-member function
- you can use many predefined lazy functions for things like construction or most of STL (`#include <boost/phoenix/stl.hpp>`).

  Incidentally. `phoenix::size` doesn't work for your type because it doesn't adhere to STL conventions (`size_t T::size() const` instead of
  `get_size`).
- You can write your own actors as polymorphic function objects, and adapt them either

  - with BOOST_FUNCTION_ADAPT_CALLABLE
  - with `phoenix::function<>`

  *In fact my favorite take on this has become `px::function f = [](auto& a, auto& b) { return a + b; };`, fully [leveraging C++17 CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)*

Let's demonstrate all or most of these.

### Step #1 Pinning Down Behaviour

As mentioned in my comment, I'm a bit confused by the apparent behavior of the parser as given, so let's first pin it down using the `phoenix::bind` approach as an example:

```
template <typename It> struct Read_frame : qi::grammar<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> {
    Read_frame() : Read_frame::base_type(data_parser) {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        tag_parser = qi::byte_;

        auto _size = px::bind(&Tag::get_size, _1);
        constexpr qi::_a_type _len;

        data_parser                                  //
            = tag_parser[(_len = _size, _val = 0)]   //
            >> qi::repeat(_len)[                     //
                   qi::byte_[_val += (_1 << --_len)] //
        ];
    }

    qi::rule<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> data_parser;
    qi::rule<It, Tag()> tag_parser;
};
```

Note several other simplifications/readability tricks. Now with some test cases **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fv1cY6eWK)**:

```
PASS [] -> none
PASS [0b00] -> optional(0)
PASS [0b01] -> none
PASS [0b01, 0b101010] -> optional(42)
PASS [0b10, 0b101010] -> none
PASS [0b10, 0b101010, 0b00] -> optional(84)
PASS [0b11, 0b101010, 0b00, 0b00] -> optional(168)
PASS [0b11111111] -> none
PASS [0b11111111, 0b01, 0b10, 0b11, 0b100, 0b101, 0b110, 0b111] -> optional(247)
```

### Step #2: Simplify

Instead of the mutating of the qi::local, I'd simply incrementally shift:

```
    data_parser                                    //
        = tag_parser[(_len = _size, _val = 0)]     //
        >> qi::repeat(_len)[                       //
               qi::byte_[(_val <<= 1, _val += _1)] //
    ];
```

We have the unit tests now to verify the behavior is the same: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/GnEY7eKq3)**.

### Step #3 Other Bind Approaches

As promised:

- using `phoenix::function` and C++17 lambda goodness: [Live](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/8obEW33aq)

  ```
   px::function get_size = [](Tag const& tag) { return tag.get_size(); };

   data_parser                                       //
       = tag_parser[(_len = get_size(_1), _val = 0)] //
       >> qi::repeat(_len)[                          //
              qi::byte_[(_val <<= 1, _val += _1)]    //
   ];
  ```

  Note that the nature of deferred function objects is polymorphic, so this works just the same:

  ```
   px::function get_size = [](auto& tag) { return tag.get_size(); };
  ```
- using the same without C++17 goodness: [Live](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/1KMYsrbEM)

  ```cpp
  template <typename It> struct Read_frame : qi::grammar<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> {
      Read_frame() : Read_frame::base_type(data_parser) {
          using namespace qi::labels;
          constexpr qi::_a_type _len;

          tag_parser = qi::byte_;

          data_parser                                       //
              = tag_parser[(_len = get_size(_1), _val = 0)] //
              >> qi::repeat(_len)[                          //
                     qi::byte_[(_val <<= 1, _val += _1)]    //
          ];
      }

    private:
      struct get_size_f {
          auto operator()(Tag const& tag) const { return tag.get_size(); };
      };
      px::function<get_size_f> get_size{};

      qi::rule<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> data_parser;
      qi::rule<It, Tag()> tag_parser;
  };
  ```
- using adaptation macros (`BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_CALLABLE`), [Live](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/aYhfPYcK4)

  ```
   namespace {
       struct get_size_f {
           auto operator()(Tag const& tag) const { return tag.get_size(); };
       };

       BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_CALLABLE(get_size_, get_size_f, 1);
   } // namespace

   template <typename It> struct Read_frame : qi::grammar<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> {
       Read_frame() : Read_frame::base_type(data_parser) {
           using namespace qi::labels;
           constexpr qi::_a_type _len;

           tag_parser = qi::byte_;

           data_parser                                        //
               = tag_parser[(_len = get_size_(_1), _val = 0)] //
               >> qi::repeat(_len)[                           //
                      qi::byte_[(_val <<= 1, _val += _1)]     //
           ];
       }

     private:
       qi::rule<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> data_parser;
       qi::rule<It, Tag()> tag_parser;
   };
  ```

### BONUS Simplify #2

Still using Qi, I would note that there is nothing in the `Tag` that necessitates using that as an attribute type. In fact, we need only the trivial bit mask which might be a free function, if you really want. So, this minimal code does the same without much of the unneeded complexity:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/E9ahGr56e)**

```cpp
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> struct Read_frame : qi::grammar<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> {
    Read_frame() : Read_frame::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        start                                          //
            = qi::byte_[(_val = 0, _a = _1 & 0b111)]   //
            >> qi::repeat(_a)[                         //
                   qi::byte_[(_val <<= 1, _val += _1)] //
        ];
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, uint32_t(), qi::locals<uint8_t>> start;
};
```

A free function would be just as easy: **[Live](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/hMeqvjjY6)**

```
start                                                         //
    = qi::byte_[(_val = 0, _a = px::bind(size_from_tag, _1))] //
    >> qi::repeat(_a)[                                        //
           qi::byte_[(_val <<= 1, _val += _1)]                //
];
```

### BONUS Simplify And Modernize

In real life, I'd certainly code a custom parser. You can do so in Spirit Qi, but to go with the times, vastly reduce compile times and just generally make my life easier, I'd go with Spirit X3:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/MPTzWah8c)**

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace Readers {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    static constexpr uint8_t size_from_tag(uint8_t tag) { return tag & 0b111; }

    struct frame_parser : x3::parser<frame_parser> {
        using attribute_type = uint32_t;
        bool parse(auto& first, auto last, auto&& /*ctx*/, auto&& /*rcontext*/, auto& attr) const {
            if (first == last)
                return false;
            auto    save = first;
            uint8_t tag  = *first++;
            uint8_t len  = size_from_tag(tag);

            uint32_t val = 0;
            while (len && first != last) {
                --len;
                val <<= 1;
                val += static_cast<uint8_t>(*first++);
            }

            if (len == 0) {
                attr = val;
                return true;
            }
            first = save;
            return false;
        }
    } static frame;
} // namespace Readers

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/std.h>
int main() {
    using Data = std::vector<uint8_t>;

    struct {
        Data                    input;
        std::optional<uint32_t> expected;
    } static const cases[]{
        {{}, {}}, // empty input, expect nothing in return
        {{0b0000}, 0},
        {{0b0001}, {}},                     // missing byte
        {{0b0001, 42}, 42},                 // 42
        {{0b0010, 42}, {}},                 // missing byte
        {{0b0010, 42, 0}, 2 * 42},          // 2*42
        {{0b0011, 42, 0, 0}, 4 * 42},       // 4*42
        {{0xff}, {}},                       // requires 7 bytes
        {{0xff, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 247}, // like this
    };

    for (auto& [data, expected] : cases) {
        std::optional<uint32_t> actual;

        auto ok      = parse(begin(data), end(data), -Readers::frame, actual);
        auto pass    = (actual == expected);
        auto verdict = pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
        assert(ok); // optional parser should never fail, but we want to be sure
        if (pass)
            fmt::print("{} {::#04b} -> {}\n", verdict, data, actual);
        else
            fmt::print("{} {::#04b} -> {}\n\t *** expected: {}\n", verdict, data, actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Note only does this compile 10x¹ faster, I suspect it will be way easier for the compiler to optimize. Indeed this program

```
constexpr uint32_t parse_frame(auto const& input) {
    uint8_t v;
    parse(begin(input), end(input), x3::expect[Readers::frame], v);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    return parse_frame(std::array<uint8_t, 3>{0b0010, 42, 0}); // 2*42
}
```

Optimizes all the way to

```
main:
        mov     eax, 84
        ret
```

See it **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Y1aYs8T31)** including the generated assembly code

---

¹ proven by finger dipping

Comment: Ooooh. Just realized I missed the most devious option out there: [Member Pointer Operator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/operator.html#phoenix.modules.operator.member_pointer_operator). Should be something like `auto get_size = (px::arg_names::arg1->*&Tag::get_size)();` - use that if you really don't care about code legibility. Disclaimer: I couldn't even get it to work just now. But I couldn't be remiss.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely detailed explanation. I can't imagine the time you spent on this. It clarified a lot. But as you would guess, by writing such an explanation, you take the risk raising more questions :). Here you wrote about `spirit::x3`. According to your example, it seems to be more readable but are there are disadvantages that could all the same justify to use `qi` over `x3`. I also took a look at the boost tutorials regarding `x3` and there is not a single one detailing the EBNF-less way you wrote the parser. Did I miss something ?

Comment: By the way the whole point of `boost::spirit` is to write parser imitating the EBNF grammar, isn't it ?

Comment: Fair observation. I'd counter it by saying that the whole point of Spirit is to composite conventional parsers building on prefab building blocks. See e.g. [Are Semantic Actions Evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil), my stance is that you should stay on the sweet spot. If you find yourself rowing against the stream, it is time to reconsider your approach: compile time, runtime performance and maintainability will suffer otherwise. Not to mention how easy it is to create dangling references in Proto expressions (on which Phoenix builds)

Comment: In this case, I can see you parsing to a raw tagged input sequence, and have attribute conversions defined via traits (like this, maybe https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8554a2c9f491d930, [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/transform.html)). I would still prefer to have a custom directive for it (by the way, there use to be articles at least for Qi at https://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/creating-your-own-parser-component-for-spirit-qi/).

Comment: And runtime wise, does x3 perform as good as qi ? Or is it slower ? Faster ?

Comment: It always depends but in principle it will be faster because the library mechanisms are much simpler (better inlining) and move semantics are taken advantage of. Just look at the example where the entire parser is inlined and statically evaluated to `84`. I don't see how that would happen with Qi

Comment: @ sehe So, I spent some time digging into all of this I tried reproduce my Qi implementation in X3. Remark 1):  Even if it is cool that X3 takes more advantage of numerous newer features from the STL and even if the build time is definitely shorter, I did not have the impression of having gained significantly something in term of readability, for the least by basing my implementation on the tutorial (Maybe was I misusing it? Though I did not have the feeling of missing something like I did using Qi)

Comment: Remark 2): In regards to my first remark, I somehow implemented the frame_parser you wrote using X3 in your [coliru live example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/MPTzWah8c), except that I used `x3::rules` to develop it (like explained in the tuto) instead of the `parser` like you did. It required me to use the `context`. At the end of the day, your proposal was may more simple and readable. a) How did you figure that using a `parser` rather than a `rule` would a good way to go and how did you know how to do it? I mean, in the x3 doc, they never refer to it, what I think is a shame

Comment: Re Remark 1) Yeah spot on. The [statelessness of X3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469919/85371) makes it harder to do things like this.
Re Remark 2) Same thing, experience! I have jumped all the hoops enough times to know when it's not worth it. That combined with happening to know how to write a custom parser component in X3 made me go to demonstrate that. The point it, that 80-90% of your grammar can likely still be serviced by plain vanilla X3 so having your custom parser blend in could still be worth it, even though in essence it's really the same as handcoding this parser without X3.