# Grammar balancing issue

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, tree-balancing

Is it possible to force **Boost.Spirit Qi** to behave in such way, that generated grammar would be adjustable in compliance with some runtime-calculable conditions/rules/rates? For example, the input consists of language constructs, that cause the different alternatives during parsing, some more frequently, others -- less. But the order of the alternatives affects on the efficiency, i.e. runtime optimality of the grammar. In some cases it is impossible to determine in advance which alternative will be chosen more often in the case of arbitrary input (which may be strongly clustered).

I know that it is possible to append symbols to `qi::symbols` at runtime, but similar behavior would be desirable for some other parsers.

Answer (score 5):

You sadly forgot (?) to include a sample grammar. So I made up my own. It parses a language like this:

```
begin
    declare x : int;
    declare y : string;

    let x = 42;
    let y = "Life the universe and everything";

    for(ch : y)
    begin
        if (call is_alpha(ch))
        begin
            declare z : string;
            let z = call to_upper(ch);
            call print(z);
        end; 
        else call print("?");
    end;
end;
```

Now. You may notice that each "language construct" (as you refer to it in the OP) has an introducing keyword. This is on purpose.

Because, now, we can use `qi::symbols` with these introducer keywords to dispatch rules (this is known as the Nabialek trick):

```
// let's have some language constructs
feature_vardecl    = identifier >> ':' >> type >> ';';
feature_assignment = identifier >> "=" >> expression >> ';';
feature_block      = *statement >> kw["end"] >> ';' | statement;
feature_forloop    = '(' >> identifier >> ':' >> identifier > ')' >> statement;
feature_func_call  = invocation > ';';
feature_if         = ('(' > expression > ')' > statement) >> (kw["else"] > statement);

language_constructs.add
    ("declare", &feature_vardecl)
    ("let",     &feature_assignment)
    ("begin",   &feature_block)
    ("if",      &feature_if)
    ("for",     &feature_forloop)
    ("call",    &feature_func_call);
```

You can see, we store the address of the corresponding grammar rule as the value in the dictionary. Now, we employ the Nabialek trick (uses `qi::_a` local to invoke the subrule):

```
statement  = 
      (kw[language_constructs] [ qi::_a = qi::_1 ] > qi::lazy(*qi::_a))
    | (expression > ';');
```

If you wanted a more 'lightweight' grammar, you'd simply remove some features:

```
language_constructs.add
    ("let",     &feature_assignment)
    ("begin",   &feature_block)
    ("call",    &feature_func_call);
```

You *could* even dynamically add features to the `language_constructs` in response to input (e.g. a version identifier in the input, or just when parsing failed). I'm not sure whether this would be a good idea, but... it's all possible.

---

A fully functional sample that parses the above program (if supplied in `input.txt`) complete with adhoc "unit tests", distinct keyword checking support, debugging etc.:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45645a23834913bd)**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx= boost::phoenix;

using It      = std::string::const_iterator;
using Skipper = qi::space_type;
using Rule    = qi::rule<It, Skipper>;

template <typename G, size_t N>
    bool test(const char (&raw)[N], const G& grammar)
{
    std::string const input(raw, raw+N-1);
    auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));
    try
    {
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, grammar, qi::space);
        // if (f!=l) std::cerr << "remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        return ok && (f == l); 
    } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e)
    {
        // std::cout << "Expectation failure '" << e.what() << "' at '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
        return false;
    }
}

template <typename It, typename Skipper>
struct toy_grammar : qi::grammar<It, Skipper>
{
    toy_grammar() : toy_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        using boost::spirit::repository::distinct;
        static const auto kw = distinct(qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9"));

        keywords.add("let")("declare")("begin")("end")("for")("call")("if")("else");

        identifier = !kw[keywords] >> qi::lexeme [ qi::alpha >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9") ];

        assert( test("z", identifier));
        assert( test("Afgjkj_123123", identifier));
        assert(!test("1", identifier));

        type       = qi::lexeme [ kw["int"] | kw["double"]| kw["string"] | kw["boolean"]];

        assert( test("int",     type));
        assert( test("double",  type));
        assert( test("string",  type));
        assert( test("boolean", type));
        assert(!test("intzies", type));
        assert(!test("Int",     type));

        literal    = qi::lexeme [
                    qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double>>()
                    | qi::int_
                    | qi::as_string ['"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"']
                    | kw [ qi::bool_ ]
                    ];

        assert( test("42",     literal));
        assert( test("42.",    literal));
        assert( test(".0",     literal));
        assert( test("-3e+7",  literal));
        assert( test("-inf",   literal));
        assert( test("-99",    literal));
        assert( test("\"\"",   literal));
        assert( test("\"\0\"", literal));
        assert( test("true",   literal));
        assert( test("false",  literal));
        assert(!test("trueish",literal));
        assert(!test("yes",    literal));

        invocation = identifier > '(' > -(expression % ',') > ')';

        // arhem, this part left as an exercise for the reader :)
        expression = literal | identifier | (kw["call"] > invocation); 

        assert( test("-99",       expression));
        assert( test("\"santa\"", expression));
        assert( test("clause",    expression));
        assert( test("true",      expression));
        assert( test("call foo()",    expression));
        assert( test("call foo(bar, inf, false)", expression));
        assert(!test("call 42()",     expression));

        // let's have some language constructs
        feature_vardecl    = identifier >> ':' >> type >> ';';
        feature_assignment = identifier >> "=" >> expression >> ';';
        feature_block      = *statement >> kw["end"] >> ';' | statement;
        feature_forloop    = '(' >> identifier >> ':' >> identifier > ')' >> statement;
        feature_func_call  = invocation > ';';
        feature_if_else    = ('(' > expression > ')' > statement) >> (kw["else"] > statement);

        language_constructs.add
            ("declare", &feature_vardecl)
            ("let",     &feature_assignment)
            ("begin",   &feature_block)
            ("if",      &feature_if_else)
            ("for",     &feature_forloop)
            ("call",    &feature_func_call);

        statement  = 
              (kw[language_constructs] [ qi::_a = qi::_1 ] > qi::lazy(*qi::_a))
            | (expression > ';');

        assert( test("declare x : int;"                                       , statement));
        assert( test("let y = true;"                                          , statement));
        assert( test("call foo();",                                             statement));
        assert( test("call foo(bar, inf, false);",                              statement));

        assert( test("begin end;",                                              statement));
        assert( test("begin let y = x; end;",                                   statement));
        assert( test("begin let y = x; call foo(y); end;",                      statement));
        assert( test("for (x : collection) begin let y = x; call foo(y); end;", statement));

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((identifier)(type)(literal)(expression)(invocation)(statement)
                (feature_vardecl)(feature_assignment)(feature_block)(feature_forloop)(feature_func_call)(feature_if_else)
                );

        start = statement;
    }
  private:
    qi::symbols<char, Rule const*> language_constructs;
    qi::symbols<char, qi::unused_type> keywords;

    Rule start,
         identifier, type, literal, expression, invocation, 
         feature_assignment, feature_vardecl, feature_block, feature_forloop, feature_func_call, feature_if_else;

    qi::rule<It, Skipper, qi::locals<Rule const*> > statement;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ifstream ifs("input.txt", ios::binary);
    string const input(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));
    try
    {
        static const toy_grammar<It, Skipper> p;
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
                f, l,
                p,
                qi::space);

        assert(ok);

        if (f!=l)
            cout << "Program remaining unparsed: '" << string(f,l) << "'\n";
    } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e)
    {
        cout << "Expectation failure '" << e.what() << "' at '" << string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: But what to do if our grammar does not have a keywords and the backtracking processing is too expensive? How to swap rules `a` and `b` depending on conditions calculatable at runtime, when we using alternative parser `*(a | b)` (say, specific input consists of only `b`, or occurences of `a` is rare)?

Comment: Thank you for The Efforts in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit-qi. When you find the time? Or your examples is form real life?

Comment: You could still use 'plain' lazy rules (perhaps storing the current selected 'rule layout' in a `qi::local`). You could update this on the fly depending on actual measured branches. In practice though, I think there's likely more potential to optimize backtracking by judicious use of expectation points and zero-width lookaheads. In certain cases you could see the most benefit with a separate tokenizing step (Qi Lex). If you care ... it might be worth posting your code with the your optimization question.

Comment: I've written on spirit performance before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918831/how-to-benchmark-boost-spirit-parser/16931098#16931098). I just noticed that @RhuiZhou basically *[asked the same question before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883809/85371)* - which contains some information that might help you. I think I've recently shown how to dramatically reduce backtracking, I'll have to look for the link later

Comment: @Dukales hah. Found it. It's hidden in this answer around where it says: **["Also, it's excruciatingly inefficient (could do with left factorization). Fixing those"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20387628/85371)**. Sadly I haven't saved the intermediate versions so I can't easily show you the difference, but I can assure you it made a huge (>100x) difference in debug output - a good indication of the amount of backtracking

Comment: I cannot accept the answer in present form, as the question was about automatically self-adaptive grammar qua.

Comment: Oh well. No problem. I can't accept the question in it's present form, because it asks for a ready made solution to an underspecified problem. For free :) It's a free world.

Comment: In any case, you are doing quite a lot. I am very grateful.

Comment: Thanks. I like contributing on SO :/ It helps me a lot too. I hope you will tackle your challenges. If some information helped, it'll be good enough.