# In boost-spirit is there any way to create grammars by function call in order to reduce code?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

The following code crashes. I suspect that the grammar cannot be copied.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_no_case.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_function.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_function_object.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>


namespace test
{
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
template<typename IT>
auto make_keyword_parser(const char *const _p, const bool _b)
{   return (qi::eps(_b) >> qi::lit(_p)) | (qi::eps(!_b) >> qi::no_case[qi::lit(_p)]);
}
template<typename IT>
struct booleanParser:qi::grammar<IT, bool(), qi::space_type>
{   qi::rule<IT, bool(), qi::space_type> m_sStart;
    booleanParser(const bool _b)
        :booleanParser::base_type(m_sStart, "booleanParser")
    {   m_sStart = make_keyword_parser<IT>("true", _b)[qi::_val = true]
            | make_keyword_parser<IT>("false", _b)[qi::_val = false];
    }
};
}
int main()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    test::booleanParser<const char*> sGrammar(false);
    bool b;
    static constexpr char ac[] = "True";
    auto p = ac;
    if (!boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(p, ac + sizeof ac - 1, sGrammar, qi::space_type(), b) || p != ac + sizeof ac - 1)
        std::cerr << "error" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cerr << "b=" << b << std::endl;
}
```

The code works fine, if the body of the `make_keyword_parser()` function consists only of `return qi::lit(_p);`.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27816065/17358702

answers this. 

boost::proto::deep_copy is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reading your code, I've treated multiple very similar questions in the past.

The TL;DR is "Here be dragons" as it is very easy to accidentally invoke Undefined Behaviour due the fact that Phoenix expressions are not meant to be named, so liberally contain references to temporaries.

- Here a meta answer that might interest you in particular [Boost.Spirit: Setup sub-grammar during parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790320/boost-spirit-setup-sub-grammar-during-parsing/17796038#17796038) which links to the following examples

  - [Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550)
  - [C++ Boost qi recursive rule construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405500/c-boost-qi-recursive-rule-construction/17408206#17408206)
  - [Boost.Spirit.Qi: dynamically create "difference" parser at parse time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000897/boost-spirit-qi-dynamically-create-difference-parser-at-parse-time/17003832?r=SearchResults&s=14%7C24.2542#17003832)
- [Combining rules at runtime and returning rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722452/combining-rules-at-runtime-and-returning-rules/49722855?r=SearchResults&s=18%7C19.3225#49722855)
- [in boost::spirit::qi, is it possible to dynamically modify rule definition in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838886/in-boostspiritqi-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-modify-rule-definition-in-ru/19883809?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C51.0132#19883809)
- [Boost.Spirit.Qi crashes when assigning rule to a sequence including itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158897/boost-spirit-qi-crashes-when-assigning-rule-to-a-sequence-including-itself/20167382?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C34.0168#20167382)
- [Boost Qi Composing rules using Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812715/boost-qi-composing-rules-using-functions/27816065?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C51.7796#27816065)
- [Is it possible to use "boost::spirit::qi::as_string" in a loop? If so, can someone help me find the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074989/is-it-possible-to-use-boostspiritqias-string-in-a-loop-if-so-can-someo/76076246?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C46.4475#76076246)

Practically all these posts will spend some time avoiding the UB traps, so caveat emptor.

Now let me read the question code and see whether I can add something specific to that.

### Review

Indeed your code also suffered the UB. You can avoid it by requesting a deep-copy of your phoenix-expression when you return it:

```
return qi::copy((qi::eps(_b) >> _p) | (qi::eps(!_b) >> qi::no_case[_p]));
```

`qi::copy` is just a convenience shorthand for `boost::proto::deep_copy`.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62605eda1d10578b)**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace test {
    template <typename IT> auto make_keyword_parser(char const* const _p, bool const _b) {
        return qi::copy((qi::eps(_b) >> _p) | (qi::eps(!_b) >> qi::no_case[_p]));
    }

    template <typename It> struct booleanParser : qi::grammar<It, bool()> {
        booleanParser(bool const _b) : booleanParser::base_type(m_sStart, "booleanParser") {
            m_sStart = make_keyword_parser<It>("true", _b)[qi::_val = true] |
                make_keyword_parser<It>("false", _b)[qi::_val = false];
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<It, bool()> m_sStart;
    };
} // namespace test

int main() {
    for (bool opt : {true, false}) {
        std::cout << " --- Opt: " << std::boolalpha << opt << std::endl;
        test::booleanParser<char const*> sGrammar(opt);

        static constexpr auto txt = "True"sv;

        if (bool b; parse(begin(txt), end(txt), sGrammar >> qi::eoi, b))
            std::cout << "b=" << b << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 --- Opt: true
error
 --- Opt: false
b=true
```

I'd be remiss if I didn't make a few remarks:

- don't expose the skipper. The caller has no business overriding your skipper, it belongs to the grammar
- don't use a skipper on a lexeme (boolParser is a lexeme)
- don't check of iterators after the fact, specify `qi::eoi` in the parser
- Your `make_keyword_parser` does a few strange things:

  - it doesn't create a keyword parser (a keyword parser  would logically check that the end of the match is on a word/identifier boundary). I've shown you before how to do it (commenting that particular purpose in the code). Probably on more than one occasion (I forget) but certainly in my last answer to you :)
  - it creates a dynamica rule, where the `_b` argument isn't dynamic. Consider just returning a static rule, something like

    ```
    template <typename Attr = qi::unused_type, typename It>
    auto const& make_keyword_parser(char const* const _p, bool const _b) {
        static const qi::rule<It, Attr()> //
            pcs = _p,                     //
            pci = qi::no_case[_p];

        return _b ? pcs : pci;
    }
    ```

  That way you don't repeatedly pay runtime cost.
- In fact creating an entire `grammar<>` around a single `rule` just adds overhead and no features. I'd do away with the grammar (which adds debugging transparency by not going through a rule named "m_sStart". Instead you can name it `"booleanValue"` or something
- Prefer `qi::symbols<char, bool>`; it will be more efficient and less error prone (e.g. when several options in the mapping can share prefixes)
- If you don't want that, consider `qi::attr(x)` instead of semantic-action `[ _val = x ]`. This is particularly nifty with `qi::match`

I think that's about it for now.

Comment: Added my look at the question code